# System.loadLibrary() can't find a shared library on linux

Tags: java, linux, shared-libraries

My Linux (Ubuntu 22.04) has the FluidSynth library package installed:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     22 févr.  3  2022 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfluidsynth.so.3 -> libfluidsynth.so.3.0.5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 551240 févr.  3  2022 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfluidsynth.so.3.0.5
```

My java 17 program uses `System.loadLibrary("fluidsynth")` to load the shared library.

It does not find the library using the default java search path:

```
no fluidsynth in java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
```

I tried running my program with `-Djava.library.path=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, but same problem:

```
no fluidsynth in java.library.path: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

I checked that the fluidsynth lib is in the ldconfig cache:

```
> ldconfig -p | grep fluid
libfluidsynth.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfluidsynth.so.3
```

I'm lost...

Note: I was able to make it work using the default java search path and manually copying a `libfluidsynth.so` file in `/usr/lib`. But I can't ask the program users to do this kind of hack, it should work out of the box on any Linux, as long as the fluidsynth library is installed.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that there is no `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfluidsynth.so` (with no version number).  Most libraries have symbolic links whose names end with `.so`.  I suppose you can search for the file yourself and pass it to [System.load](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#load(java.lang.String)), which unlike loadLibrary takes an absolute file name.  Have you considered using the [javax.sound.midi](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/sound/midi/package-summary.html) package?

Comment: @VGR you're right, today I used System.load() and it worked! What I find strange is that the lib has several dependencies which also do not end with .so, but still it worked. It's like the first search is made by Java and needs a .so, then it's done by the Linux linker which can handle the .so.xx.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `System.load("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfluidsynth.so.3");` which works and loads the lib plus all its dependencies. It's not perfect though, because I need to locate the library file first.

It's still not clear to me why java does not accept `*.so.version` for the initial lib, but accept it for its dependencies.